# NbClust - Error: cannot allocate vector of size x

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am running k-means clustering in R and would like to use `NbClust` to help identify the optimal number of clusters. My dataset, `df`, has 636,688 rows and 7 columns.

When I run `NbClust(df, min.nc = 2, max.nc = 3, method = "kmeans")`, I get:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1510.1 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In dist(jeu, method = "euclidean") :
  Reached total allocation of 32767Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In dist(jeu, method = "euclidean") :
  Reached total allocation of 32767Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In dist(jeu, method = "euclidean") :
  Reached total allocation of 32767Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In dist(jeu, method = "euclidean") :
  Reached total allocation of 32767Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Here is my `sessionInfo`:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] clusterSim_0.43-3 fpc_2.1-6         flexmix_2.3-11    mclust_4.2        cluster_1.14.4    MASS_7.3-29      
 [7] flexclust_1.3-4   modeltools_0.2-21 lattice_0.20-23   NbClust_1.4       rattle_2.6.26    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] ade4_1.6-2     class_7.3-9    e1071_1.6-2    nnet_7.3-7     parallel_3.0.2 R2HTML_2.2.1   rgl_0.93.996   tools_3.0.2
```

Is there any way to get around the size limitation? I know that I can sample and run `NbClust` on the samples, although I have found that my sample has to be 1% of the full dataset in order for `NbClust` to be able to run - a sample I believe to be too small to be helpful, even if I do run a number of iterations. And even with small samples - `NbClust` is slow. I have looked at `cluster.stats` from the `fpc` package, but that requires a distance matrix - an impossibility for me and my large dataset.

Comment: There almost no getting around the fact that you'll need to fit a 640k x 640k matrix in memory. That's a _big_ object. So you'll need a lot of ram. I'm not aware of any clustering packages in R that leverage distance matrices stored on disk, though that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: @joran The R package biganalytics can do k-means (function `bigkmeans`) on `big.matrix`. I think that doing an svd decomposition (`irlba` package) and taking the leading eigenvectors before clustering can help in this case.

Comment: @dickoa I tried installing `biganalytics` but got the following:    `> install.packages("biganalytics")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘biganalytics’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘biganalytics’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it works only on Unix systems but I read that some have managed to install it on windows (I forgot the source) http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biganalytics/index.html

Comment: Look for **algorithms that don't need a full distance matrix** (there ARE plenty) and implementations that use **index acceleration**. Both will make them more scalable. I found [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) with STR bulk loaded R*-trees to perform very well.